# HTACCESS short url and modify my url

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, url, short

How can I use .htaccess to make this URL

http://domain.com/index.php/sub1/sub2/333

look like

http://domain.com/333

?
Thank you very much!
I tried everything and I tried to find everywhere the answer, but nothing works.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 0):

Following rule should work for you:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/?$ /index.php/sub1/sub2/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks, but still not working. It says 404 error (but the file exists)

Comment: Q1. Is this the only .htaccess or do you have another? Q2. Is this the only code in this .htaccess? If you have some other code then please post it in question? Q3. What is location of above .htaccess?

Answer (score 0):

This is my htacces, maybe can help you ( I hosted in hostgator,in hostgator is importan write  your user, if is local remove  ) this configuratio apply to multiple sites

```
      <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
         RewriteEngine On
         RewriteBase /<myuser>/%{HTTP_HOST}
         RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
         RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
         RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /<myuser>/%{HTTP_HOST}/index.php/$1 [L]
      </IfModule>
```

You can replace %{HTTP_HOST} by your folder.

After if you want modify the controller name, you need modify in application/config/routes.php